# Send multiple Excel workbooks to relevant recipients

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have around 40 individual reports saved as Excel workbooks, to be sent to 40 different groups of recipients. The file name used for the workbook contains the names of the recipients.

This is part of the VBA macro to send the email:

```
Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem

With mail
.To = “[Recipient1]; [Recipient2]; [Recipient3}”
.Subject = “Monthly Report”
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = “<p>Please find attached monthly X Report</p>”
.Attachments.Add “Documents/MrX;MrY”
.Display
End With
```

I would like to use the file name as the `MailItem.To` field for each workbook.

Comment: Your question lacks any evidence of any effort or research on your side. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask], then edit your question and provide more detail before it gets locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send email through VBA you can mainly use the Microsoft CDO for Windows Library or the Microsoft 16.0 Object Library (or earlier version). To use those libraries ([after adding them](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/add-object-library-reference-vba/)) you can use different tutorials available online to help you get started.

### Using Microsoft CDO

- [Send an Email using Excel Macro from Gmail or Yahoo](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/12/how-to-send-an-email-using-excel-macro-from-gmail-or-yahoo/)
- [How Can I Attach a File to an Email Sent Using CDO?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-an-email-sent-using-cdo/)

### Using the Outlook Object

- [How To Send Email From Excel with Outlook using VBA](https://powerspreadsheets.com/send-email-excel-vba/)

As for the multiple recipients issue, I'd suggest using a `For loop` over a range where you have listed the recipients list in one column and the file path of the workbooks to send in another column.